# Flask SQLAlchemy dynamically update pickle type column?

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I don't know which column I'm accessing until runtime, so I need a dynamic way to update this information. I am currently using the getattr function on the current_user object included with the flask_login lib to access this information, but I can't update it this way.

I've tried directly changing the value using the getattr function, but it just raises an error.

Comment: Please Provide the code and the error.